# Is there a way to record a video call on the ipad? Video call could be w/ Skype, Facetime, etc

Tags: video, ipad

I need to record a video call to someone on an iPad.

Any suggestions on what /how to do that?

I'd be using a Windows PC or iPad2 on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging it into your computer then open quicktime. Right click quicktime > New Movie Recording > click the dropdown menu [image: dropdown menu] > Select your iphone + change any sound settings you desire.

Might need to tweak a bit on windows. Also, make sure you deal with the legality of recording video calls.

Answer (score 0):

[First result on Google for "windows record ipad screen".](http://x-mirage.com/x-mirage/) These only work for Airplay-compatible apps. If you want to record anything on the iPad screen the only official way is using QuickTime on a Mac.